# Cómo puedo mejorar este código de un algoritmo de una lista de números del 0 al 3?

Tags: python

Hice un código para un problema que consiste en que te dan 3 parámetros, el número números en la lista, las veces que se repite el algoritmo y la lista de los números.

- Si hay un 0 (0), no pasa nada (0).
- Si hay un 1, con un 0 a la derecha o izquierda (0,1), se vuelve un 2 (0,2), si no lo hay se vuelve un 0
- Si hay dos 2 seguidos, y un 0 a su izquierda (0,2,2), el 0 se vuelve un 1 y los doses, treses (1,3,3), si no hay un cero a la derecha, lo mismo a la izquierda. Si no hay ningún cero a los lados, no pasa nada.
- Si hay un 3, que tenga un 0 a 2 o menos posiciones de él (2,3,2,0), se vuelve un 2 (2,2,2,0), por el contrario, si no lo hay, se vuelve un 0.

Después, se devuelve con un print() la nueva lista tantas veces como te lo pida la función, incluyendo el estado inicial.

Hice este código, pero no me resulto del todo satisfactorio, ya que hay mucha repetición en los condicionales, la función `is_on_range` no me gusto como quedo, y otras cosas, como que hay líneas excesivamente largas.

Pregunto si alguien fuese capaz de mejorar el código, o más fácil, apuntar cosas que podría mejorar.

Las variables se llaman así porque en el problema original trata sobre organismos en diferentes celdas que evolucionan por cada día que pasa.

```py
def is_on_range(number, length, aux): # Si el índice esta fuera de rango, lo remplaza por otro
  return number if number < length and number >= 0 else aux

def organisms_evolution(cells, days, organisms): 
  if cells != len(organisms):
    print("The number of cells isn't equal to the lenght of the list of organisms")
    return
  print(organisms)
  for i in range(days): # Cada vez que se repite
    new_organisms = [] # Nueva lista, en la que se añade lso números según evolucionan
    j = 0
    while j < len(organisms): # Recorre la lista se números
      list_length = len(organisms)
      if organisms[j] == 0: # Si hay 0, nada
        new_organisms.append(0)
      elif organisms[j] == 1: # Comprueba si hay un 0 cerca
        if  0 in [organisms[is_on_range(j-1, list_length, j)], organisms[is_on_range(j+1, list_length, j-1)]]:
          new_organisms.append(2)
        else:
          new_organisms.append(0)
      elif organisms[j] == 2: # Es dos?
        if 2 == organisms[is_on_range(j+1, list_length, organisms.index(min(organisms)))]: # Hay dos consecutivos?
          if organisms[is_on_range(j-1, list_length, j)] == 0: # Hay 0 en izq
            new_organisms[-1] = 1 # Remplza el 0 por un 1 al ser anterior (el último valor en la nueva lista)
            new_organisms.append(3)
            new_organisms.append(3)
            j+=1
          elif organisms[is_on_range(j+2, list_length, j-1)] == 0: # Hay 0 en dcha
            new_organisms.append(3)
            new_organisms.append(3)
            new_organisms.append(1)
            j+=2
          else: # No hay 0
            new_organisms.append(2)
        else: # No hay dos 2
          new_organisms.append(2)
      elif organisms[j] == 3: # Es tres
        if 0 in [organisms[is_on_range(j-2, list_length, j)], organisms[is_on_range(j-1, list_length, j)], organisms[is_on_range(j+1, list_length, j-1)], organisms[is_on_range(j+2, list_length, j)]]: # Tiene 0 cerca?
          new_organisms.append(2)
        else:
          new_organisms.append(0)
      j+=1
    organisms = new_organisms
    print(new_organisms)

organisms_evolution(15, 6, [0,0,2,2,1,0,3,3,3,1,2,2,0,2,3])
```

Comment: Hola! No siento que la pregunta encaje con el formato del sitio, pero pregunté y pareciera que podemos verlo en una sala de chat si querés. Cuando quieras y yo esté listo podemos verlo c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A veces lo primero que hay que hacer es *linealizar* el algoritmo de modo que se centre en cada elemento en lugar de en grupos de elementos:

Se produce un cambio si:

- si hay un 0 precedido o seguido por dos 2, se vuelve 1
- si hay un 1 precedido o seguido por 0, se vuelve 2, si no se vuelve 0
- si hay un 2 precedido por 0 y seguido por 2, o precido por 2 y seguido por 0, se vuelve 3
- si hay un 3 precedido o seguido por 0 en dos posiciones, se vuelve 2, si no se vuelve 0

También es conveniente pensar en los *"invariantes"* que tienes. En este caso, el número de células y la longitud de la lista serán lo mismo y no cambiará durante el algoritmo una vez te has asegurado que coinciden. Así mismo, no conviene modificar la lista durante el proceso, mejor crear otra.

En concreto, podemos crear una función genérica para obtener los elementos precedentes o siguientes que controle los errores:

```py
def get_item(i: int) -> int:
  return organisms[i] if 0 <= i < cells else -1
```

Definamos el algoritmo:

```py
def mutation(pos: int, cell: int) -> int:
    if cell == 0:
        if get_item(pos-1)==2 and get_item(pos-2)==2:
            return 1
        elif get_item(pos+1)==2 and get_item(pos+2)==2:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    elif cell == 1:
        return 2 if get_item(pos-1) == 0 or get_item(pos+1) == 0 else 0
    elif cell == 2:
        if get_item(pos-1)==0 and get_item(pos+1)==2:
            return 3
        elif get_item(pos-1)==2 and get_item(pos+1)==0:
            return 3
        else:
            return 2
    elif cell == 3:
        if get_item(pos-2)==0 or get_item(pos-1)==0 or get_item(pos+1)==0 or get_item(pos+2)==0:
            return 2
        else:
            return 0
```

Esta forma de definir un algoritmo es demasiado *"imperativa"*, muy fácil de equivocarte. Es mejor pasar a una definición más *"declarativa"*:

```py
def mutation(pos: int, cell: int) -> int:
    # neighbors at distance 2
    neighbors = [get_item(i) for i in (pos-2, pos-1, pos+1, pos+2)]
    if cell == 0:
        cond = (neighbors[0:2] == [2,2]) or (neighbors[2:4] == [2,2]) 
        return 1 if cond else 0
    elif cell == 1:
        cond = (neighbors[1] == 0) or (neighbors[2] == 0)
        return 2 if cond else 0
    elif cell == 2:
        cond = (neighbors[1] == 0 and neighbors[2] == 2) or \
               (neighbors[1] == 2 and neighbors[2] == 0)
        return 3 if cond else 2
    elif cell == 3:
        cond = 0 in neighbors
        return 2 if cond else 0
```

Para aplicar el algoritmo:

```py
def organisms_evolution(cells, days, organisms): 
  assert cells == len(organisms), "The number of cells isn't equal to the lenght of the list of organisms"

  for _ in range(days):
    organisms_next = [mutation(pos, cell) for pos, cell in enumerate(organisms)]
    organisms = organisms_next

  return organisms
```

### Código completo

Quedaría refactorizar un poco para que quede mejor. Una opción sería crear una clase que tuviera los parámetros del algoritmo como atributos. Por no liar más, dejo una versión como función:

```py
def mutation(ns: list[int]) -> int:
    cell = ns[2]
    if cell == 0:
        cond = (ns[0:2] == [2,2]) or (ns[3:5] == [2,2]) 
        return 1 if cond else 0
    elif cell == 1:
        cond = (ns[1] == 0) or (ns[3] == 0)
        return 2 if cond else 0
    elif cell == 2:
        cond = (ns[1] == 0 and ns[3] == 2) or \
               (ns[1] == 2 and ns[3] == 0)
        return 3 if cond else 2
    elif cell == 3:
        cond = 0 in ns
        return 2 if cond else 0
        

def organisms_evolution(cells, days, organisms): 
  assert cells == len(organisms), "The number of cells isn't equal to the lenght of the list of organisms"
  
  def get_item(i: int) -> int:
    return organisms[i] if 0 <= i < cells else -1

  def neighbors(pos: int) -> list[int]:
    return [get_item(i) for i in (pos-2, pos-1, pos, pos+1, pos+2)]

  for _ in range(days):
    organisms_next = [mutation(neighbors(pos)) for pos, cell in enumerate(organisms)]
    organisms = organisms_next

  return organisms


if __name__ == "__main__":
  lista=[0,0,2,2,1,0,3,3,3,1,2,2,0,2,3]
  print(organisms_evolution(15, 6, lista))
```

---

### Edición:

Pensándolo mejor, se podría aplicar *pattern matching* para una solución más clara:

```py
def mutation(ns: list[int]) -> int:
    match ns:
        case [2,2,0,_,_] | [_,_,0,2,2]:
            return 1
        case [_,_,0,_,_]:
            return 0
        case [_,0,1,_,_] | [_,_,1,0,_]:
            return 2
        case [_,_,1,_,_]:
            return 0
        case [_,0,2,2,_] | [_,2,2,0,_]:
            return 3
        case [_,_,2,_,_]:
            return 2
        case [_,_,3,_,_] if 0 in ns:
            return 2
        case [_,_,3,_,_]:
            return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

He editado tu código aplicando conceptos un poco más avanzados.

Para el tema de las líneas muy largas he creado unas funciones lambda que te van a ayudar bastante.

```
check_in_range=lambda value, length: 0<=value<length
get_indexes=lambda *indexes, lista=organisms_copia, length=length: [lista[index_] for index_ in indexes if check_in_range(index_, length)]
```

Esas dos funciones sería equivalente a hacer lo siguiente:

```
def check_in_range(value, length):
    return 0<=value<length  # Devuelve True or False

def get_indexes(*indexes, lista = organisms_copia, length = length)
    lista1 = []
    for index_ in indexes:
        if check_in_range(index_, length):
            lista1.append(lista[index_])
    return lista1
```

## Código completo

```
def organisms_evolution(cells: int, days: int, organisms: list):
    '''Make replacements in a list (organisms) of a determined length (cells) for many (days) times'''

    if cells != len(organisms):
        print("The number of cells isn't equal to the lenght of the list of organisms")
        return

    for _ in range(days):
        # Utilizamos iter para poder saltar iteraciones, tú para saltar hacías i+=2, ahora se hará con next(lista)
        lista=iter(range(length:=len(organisms)))
        # Creamos una lista que será la referencia sobre la que verificaremos las condiciones, sin esto habría errores --> [3, 1] <-> [0, 2]
        organisms_copia=organisms.copy()
        # Funciones para comprobar si el índice es válido y para devolver los índices de una lista en caso de que sean válidos
        check_in_range=lambda value, length: 0<=value<length
        get_indexes=lambda *indexes, lista=organisms_copia, length=length: [lista[index_] for index_ in indexes if check_in_range(index_, length)]

        for i in lista:  # En vez de definir i=0 e ir sumando +1, recorremos el generador y listo
            if organisms_copia[i]==1:
                # Se convierte en un 2 si hay un 0 a su izquierda o derecha, si no se convierte en 0
                organisms[i] = 2 if 0 in get_indexes(i-1, i+1) else 0

            elif organisms_copia[i]==2:
                if get_indexes(i-1, i, i+1)==[0,2,2]:
                    # Asignación múltiple
                    organisms[i-1:i+2]=[1, 3, 3]
                    next(lista)  # [..., 0, 2, 2, n, ...]
                                 #           |-->|

                elif get_indexes(i, i+1, i+2)==[2,2, 0]:
                    # Asignación multiple
                    organisms[i:i+3]=[3, 3, 1]
                    next(lista)
                    next(lista) # [..., 2, 2, 0, n ...]
                                #        |----->|

            elif organisms_copia[i]==3:
                # Se convierte en 2 si hay un 0 a 2 o menos posiciones, si no se convierte en 0
                organisms[i] = 2 if 0 in get_indexes(i-2, i-1, i+1, i+2) else 0

        # Actualizamos el valor de la lista de referencia
        organisms_copia=organisms
        print(organisms_copia)

    return organisms

lista=[0,0,2,2,1,0,3,3,3,1,2,2,0,2,3]

print(organisms_evolution(15, 6, lista))
```